# JS function activates alert on page reload

Tags: javascript

so i'm working on this shop system for a webpage i'm working on

but after i added this to the js

```
function s1u1f() {
  if (S1U1 === false && script1B === true && Points >= 100) {
        Points = Points - 100;
        clearInterval(script1);
        s1ut.innerHTML = "UPGRADE2";
        ids1.innerHTML = "this will speed <br /> up script1 <br /> to 0,500s";
        s1p.innerHTML = "Price: 125P";
        script1 = setInterval(function() {click(1);}, 750);
        S1U1B.removeEventListener("click", s1u1f());
    }else if (100 > Points) {
        alert("you dont have enough points to buy this item");
    }else if (script1B === false) {
        alert("You need to buy script1 first");
    }
}
```

it automatically activates the alert within the `else if(100 > Points)`

if you want to see what i mean go to this link
http://clickthebutton.esy.es/clickthebutton%20layout%20demo/cssTest.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line (not shown above) is the problem:

```
S1U1B.addEventListener("click", s1u1f());
```

That calls the `s1u1f()` function immediately. There are `0` points at startup, so `100 > Points`, and you see the `alert()`.

You want to pass the function, not call it:

```
S1U1B.addEventListener("click", s1u1f);
```

You'll also want to change:

```
S1U1B.removeEventListener("click", s1u1f());
```

to

```
S1U1B.removeEventListener("click", s1u1f);
```

for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you're creating your click handler:

```
S1U1B.addEventListener("click", s1u1f());
```

You need to pass in a function reference, but instead you're calling the function immediately.  Remove the parens on your function:

```
S1U1B.addEventListener("click", s1u1f);
```